# How do I automate power in 2021?

Tags: astroneer

Here's the situation - trying to plan out a base that uses generators to fill in power when the wind and solar (and base/RTG power) are insufficient.

Ideally, I'd like to have the generators kick in when there's not enough power to supply needs, but the power sensor seems to be an all-or-nothing trigger (and if you don't isolate the sensor, the generators themselves trigger the sensor to turn off!)

Second best would be to use the battery sensor and have the generators kick in when they batteries empty, and run until they fill. Problem I'm having there is that you have to attach the sensor to a specific battery, and there seems to be no logic I can find to what order batteries get drained/refilled.

Is there a good workaround here? My goal is to be able to keep a few atmo collectors running when I'm not home without burning unnecessary resources.